# Using or avoiding a class for credentials in a Python API; what is most Pythonic?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a Python 3 API that interfaces with a web service.  Each function needs at minimum a username, password, and address of the server.

For context; the API will primarily be used from the REPL as part of some data science type activities.

My first thought was to put everything in a class and then take the server address and credentials through __init__.  But then I watched this presentation http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes called "Stop Writing Classes," and I thought maybe I don't need a class.

There seems to be four possible approaches:

1)  Take the server address and credentials as parameters to each function and just type them out every time a function is used to make an API call  (Does not seem humane)

2)  Same as approach as 1 but use functools.partial to avoid retyping the server address and credentials over and over again

3)  Create a config method and store them as global variables in the module

4)  Return to plan A and use a class

What would be the most Pythonic approach or is there a better fifth option that I am not considering?

Comment: You could use a dictionary. But there's no need to overthink things, classes would work too.

Comment: Thanks Simeon; maybe I should ask the question a different way.  I'm now leaning towards option 2, using functools.partial, is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

In this case a class is more Pythonic.

Why?

You have:

- state: `username`, `password`, `server`.
- functions:  I don't know what they're called, you didn't specify
- the functions use the state + additional info to do their job

According to the talk the warning sign is when your class only has two functions, one of which is `__init__` -- this is not the case with your code.